# How function double,int work? c++

Tags: c++, function

Could you explain me how these functions work?

```
double f(int i)
{
    cout<<"a";
    return 1;
}

int f(double i)
{
    cout<<"b";
    return 1;
}
```

For:

```
f(f(f(1)));
```

In my opinion the result should be:    `aaa`
but it is`aba`

And same situation with `f(f(f(1.1)));`
I think there should be `aab`  but there is `bab`

Comment: _In my opinion the result should be:  aaa.._ Why?

Comment: What, exactly is unclear about it? Why do you think it should be `aaa`?

Comment: f(1)=1, f(f(1))=1 f(f(f(1)))=1.

Comment: @Finer `f(1) = 1.0`

Comment: `1` is an `int`. `1.0` is a `double`. They appear as and represent the same thing, but are treated differently

Comment: @Fureeish "appear as" they're different sizes, with different formats, I wouldn't say that appear as each other at all.

Comment: The propertity of size determinates what they are, not how they appear. They represent *and appear* as a value **1**. When we distinguish `1.0` and `1` we are talking about the properties. I get what you are saying though - they are different things, but the fact that they can be mistakenly treated as the same one is a interpretation of *false appearance*.

Comment: @Finer "_f(1)=1, f(f(1))=1 f(f(f(1)))=1_" Value doesn't matter. All that matters, in overload resolution, is the type. Consider learning from a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: But they don't appear as each other at all!  Debuggers won't print "1" when you inspect them.  If you're thinking about how cout handles them then you can add `<< "1"` and `<< '1'` to the list; but they certainly don't appear to be an int of value 1 either!

Answer (score 15):

When you return from a function, the type of the return value is determined **from the function prototype**, not what it's written as-is. If the type doesn't match, it'll be implicitly converted to the correct type. So this example function:

```
double foo(void) { return 1; }
```

Actually returns `double(1)`, or equivalently, `1.0`. It does **not** return an `int` because `1` is int. It does, however, convert your `int` to a `double` value to match the function's return value type as declared.

So coming to your question, the innermost function called is `double f(int)`, and the second function called is `int f(double)`, and the outermost function called is `double f(int)`. This matched the output you see: `aba`.

```
f( f( f(1) ) );
↑  ↑  ↑
|  |  calls double f(int)
|  calls int f(double)
calls double f(int)
```

Answer (score 5):

The way the compiler reads your `f(f(f(1)));` function is from the inside out. Let me elaborate, the compiler sees `f(1);` and it looks for a function called **f** that takes an **int** as an argument so that would be:

```
 double f(int i)
{
    cout<<"a";
    return 1;
}
```

Now, once your function executes, it returns a **double**, hence the second **f** takes in a double -> which calls your next function that takes double

```
int f(double i)
{
    cout<<"b";
    return 1;
}
```

Following the logic explained above, we have arrived at the last/outer layer of your triple f question. Now the compiler has an **int** and is looking for a function called f that takes int -> which is your first declared function.

And that is why you get aba as a result.

Answer (score 1):

prior to your first use of std::cout in your code, add the line

```
std::cout << std::fixed;
```

This changes the output (of parameter i) quite a bit by causing int and double to show their 'true colors'.  Perhaps this will illustrates what is happening.

Example:

```
double f(int i)
   {
      std::cout << "  a" << std::setw(9) << i << "    " << std::flush;
      return 1;
   }

int f(double i)
   {
      std::cout << "  b" << std::setw(9) << i << "    " << std::flush;
      return 1;
   }

int main(int , char** )
{
   std::cout << std::fixed << "\n";

   f(f(f(1)));

   std::cout << std::endl;

   f(f(f(1.0)));

   return 0;
}
```

Generates output:

```
 a        1      b 1.000000      a        1    
 b 1.000000      a        1      b 1.000000
```

The returned value (always integer 1) is implicitly transformed to the return type, which is different for the two functions.

Which function is invoked is determined by the signature of the function, i.e. the parameters actual type.  This also illustrates that the return type is **not** part of the signature.